# increase the width of a column dynamically in jasper reports in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

How do i increase the width of a column in jasper reports dynamically in java, i have tried changing many things in java side like reading the style sheet and changing the values. But in this case i don't know how to initialize the method which will read the width and change it.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your report variable is called `jasperReport`

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
```

You need to get the band (JRBand) your column is in. Assuming it is in the detail band:

```
JRBand band = jasperReport.getDetail();
```

And then find your column and change it's width:

```
JRElement column = band.getElementByKey("key_for_column");
column.setWidth(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way column will use full page width available

```java
myReport.addColumn(myColumn);
myReport.setTitle("column should use full width available");
myReport.setUseFullPageWidth(true); //make colums to fill the page width
```